# HighCharts - Column style, interval of 5 minutes

Tags: highcharts

I want to display a Highcharts.com column-style chart with a column interval of exactly 5 minutes. My database contains data for every minute. Now I see irregular gaps of sometimes 6 or 7 minutes in my chart. So e.g. 10:05 a.m., 10:10 a.m., 10:16 a.m., 10:21 a.m., etc. etc. Where do these gaps come from and why is the data not consistently read from the database from 0:00 a.m. to 12:59 p.m. in 5 minute intervals?

[image: normal size]
[image: zoomed]

Comment: Hi @282solutions, Could you provide me with some live example of the problem? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Is done, unfortunately the code does not work in the fiddle

Comment: I need to see your code to help you.

Comment: Now the Code is available. Hope you can help me. THANK YOU
Or look here please:    view-source:https://www.wetterstation-aue.de/

Comment: Thanks for the example. The problem results from the fact that the `x` values do not have a 5-minute interval. Please check the console in here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/38rtj1od/

Comment: Oh! Thank you for this Information :-)

Comment: How do I have to change the code from Line 500 at wetterstaion-aue.de so that the values are retrieved from the database at a fixed 5-minute interval? I thought it was already happening. So fixed interval like: hh:00, hh:05, hh:10, hh:15 etc

Comment: $(function () {
        function fetchLatestData(highcharts, minTimeout) {
            var data = highcharts.series[0].data,
                lastTimestamp = data[data.length - 1].x,
                timeout = Math.max(
                    (5 * 60 * 1000) - (Date.now() - lastTimestamp) + 10000,
                    typeof minTimeout === 'undefined' ? 0 : minTimeout
                );

Comment: Hi @282solutions, I don't know the structure of your database so I can't help you.